# Bash find: command returns 1 in an empty folder

Tags: bash, find

I have a script which scans a folder regulary for new files. The folder itselfe is empty most of the time. My problem is that find returns 1 if a folder is empty:

```
Mon Sep 22, 11:14:41 [0] > find ./* -maxdepth 0 -mmin +5 -type f -printf "%f\n"
find: `./*': No such file or directory
```

How can i supress this error? I'd like to get 0 as an returncode even if the folder i am searching is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `find . -maxdepth 1` instead of `find ./* -maxdepth 0`.